# Is Shimamura Christian in the original text?

Tags: adachi-and-shimamura

The Seven Seas translation of the *Adachi and Shimamura* light novels, particularly the early ones, are riddled with several artifacts that I've found just a tad annoying. One of these is that characters keep saying grace before meals. I hadn't seen it for a while, but then it popped up again in volume 6 with the Shimamura family. I'm not sure if this is limited to one character or not (I seem to recall Hino doing it too).

One example, in volume 6 chapter *The Other End of the Calendar*:

> My sister and I pressed our hands together to say grace, and by the time we lowered them, my mother had already started eating.

I'd simply like to ask whether in the original text this is actually the standard *itadakimasu*, or if the author actually was having characters say grace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is itadakimasu.

I have checked my copy of the Japanese version, and it is indeed the standard itadakimasu. I understand the wanting to localize things to make it easier for non-Japanese to understand, but changing religion is a bit overreaching. Also, it changes the timing of things, since this scene is supposed to show how speedy the mother started eating the food, and saying grace takes much longer than an itadakimasu.